# How to pass different data to multiple instances of the same test with Robo

Tags: php, testing, codeception

#### What am I trying to achieve?

I made a test which logs into a web application I have, completes an exam and submits it at the end.

I need to test how many users the server can handle so my intention is to run the same test multiple times, but I need to be able to pass each instance a different `user:password`.

Right now I have an array with the credentials inside the test itself, and I made it so it takes a random item from the array. This works but obviously, sometimes it takes the same credentials 2 times so this isn't a reliable solution.

This is my RoboFile:

```
public function parallelSplitTests()
  {
   // Split your tests by files
        $this->taskSplitTestFilesByGroups(5)
            ->projectRoot('.')
            ->testsFrom('tests/acceptance')
            ->groupsTo('tests/_data/paracept_')
            ->run();
    }
public function parallelRun()
    {
    $parallel = $this->taskParallelExec();

             for ($i = 1; $i <= 1; $i++) {

             $parallel->process(
              $this->taskCodecept() // use built-in Codecept task
            ->suite('acceptance') // run acceptance tests
            ->group("paracept_$i") // for all paracept_* groups
                ->xml("tests/_log/result_$i.xml") // save XML results
                );
            }

             return $parallel->run();
           }
```

Comment: As a thought, you could load the array and perform a shuffle on it and just step through it to prevent duplication of entries using your current method.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that every test would do that, so when "Test 1" takes one element of the array, "Test 2" doesn't know that, so it might take the same element of the array

Comment: Is like each test is isolated from the others